# Serving static files on Apache with Django (404 error)

Tags: python, django, apache, static-files

I've been trying to setup an Apache (2.2.15) as a proxy with gunicorn and django (1.6.11) on a CentOS server (6.7), but I'm stuck on a problem regarding the static files. (I'm fairly new to django)

I have already looked at the great documentation that Django provides, as well as a few other stackoverflow's posts, but to no avail.

### What I could check :

- The problem doesn't seem to come from Django or the templates, as running the development server with 'DEBUG = False' and the option '--insecure' works fine.
- It probably is a problem with the Alias and Directory block I added in my virtualhost, but I can't make sense of why it doesn't work.
- Gunicorn shouldn't have any word to say in it, as it doesn't serve static files.

### What my configuration looks like :

1) I got my project's static files into '/var/www/myproject/static' thanks to the 'collectstatic' command.

2) Then, I created the virtualhosts (where I think the problem is) :

(first one for the redirection to HTTPS)

```
<virtualhost *:80>
    ServerAdmin user@domain.com
    ServerName localhost

    ServerSignature Off
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L]
</virtualhost>
```

(second one for the actual work)

```
<virtualhost *:443>
    ServerAdmin user@domain.com
    ServerName localhost

    ServerSignature Off

    DocumentRoot /var/www/myproject

    Alias /static/ "/var/www/myproject/static/"
    <Directory "/var/www/myproject/static">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All
    </Directory>

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8000/ connectiontimeout=150 timeout=300
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8000/
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxySet http://127.0.0.1:8000/ connectiontimeout=150 timeout=300

    ... here goes the SSL and Log configuration ...
</virtualhost>
```

After a service restart, my static files weren't loaded and I had a 404 error on their get. An 'httpd -S' didn't throw any error and the rest of the functionalities of the web interface are working great.

I also tried without the ending '/' for the '/static/' alias as it seemed to be a problem for some other people, tried to move the files directly under /var/www/myproject and have them accessed without an alias with the DocumentRoot...

If you want to have a look at the django settings.py (don't know if it's relevant, but some django guru could find something wrong there too) :

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/myproject/static/'
STATIC_URL =  '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'static',),)
```

As well as the templates :

```
{% load staticfiles %}
....
<link href="{% static 'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/boostrap.min.css %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Urls.py of the project :

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', lambda x: redirect('/Collecte/')),
    url(r'^Collecte/', include('Collecte.urls', namespace="Collecte")),
) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

And the urls.py of the app (named 'Collecte'):

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from Collecte import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^Collectes/Execution/ù', views.CollExecution, name='CollExecution'),
    ... quite a lot of them ...
)

# Commented this line from a suggestion, was present at start
#urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns
```

If you feel like any file is missing for the question to be relevant, just ask for it and I'll do my best :).

Comment: are you using {% load staticfiles %} at the top of the template?

Comment: I am indeed, and it works with the runserver with the DEBUG set to False so I don't think it comes from the templates. (you never know though)

Comment: show your urls.py to server static files

Comment: Added the urls.py, don't know if that's exactly what you wanted though.

Comment: Include your proxy configuration directives.

Comment: Added the Proxy settings of the virtualhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright,

I found the answer to my question in [another stackoverflow thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/627217/gunicorn-behind-apache-link-to-localhost) that had a similar configuration (but with flask instead of django).

As Ajay Gupta said, I think I had a problem in the urls.py file of the project as I had to add 'static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)' (switched from using the staticfiles app django provides to this other way).

The other problem was in the apache virtualhost configuration, as I wanted my static files to be served by apache and not gunicorn or django. I was redirecting everything to the gunicorn server, even the requests to static files. So I had to add 'ProxyPass /static/ !' so that apache serves the files.

I don't know if it's the right way to do it, but it worked for me.

Comment: Nice one, solved my issue of serving the statics on my apache2/uwsgi setup within the same virtualhost config

Comment: @L.Fueyo nice catch with the `ProxyPass /static/ !`

Answer (score 0):

`from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns` 
 is a helper function that works only when

`debug = True`

So for instance just set `debug = True` again, restart your server and check

Comment: It doesn't work with even with debug = True. I really don't think the problem is from django as the project, if executed from the runserver (debug = False) works just fine. I'm perhaps missing something that the runserver is doing and apache is not.

Comment: I would suggest accessing a single staticfile in your browser. there might be problem with permissions

Comment: Having a look again at your answer as well as https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#runserver, I think that the problem is from what you said. But I don't really know how to solve it (as I wouldn't like to have a server with debug = True in production).

Comment: so problem is not with your apache configuration? you sure?

Comment: I'm not sure, because setting Debug = True in django doesn't work either... doesn't look like a permission problem as the user has read permissions on the whole folders and files.

Comment: can you access your static file using absolute url?

Comment: I cannot, is there a configuration in the urls.py to add so that you can access your static files ? (I get a 404)

Comment: yes there is. check the documenation. you need to add a new url 'static' which will point to your static directory

Comment: After reading a little bit more the documentation, I edited my django configuration and I can now access the files through the url if Debug is set to True (but still not if Debug is set to False). As ajay gupta said, I was missing a 'static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)' entry in my project urls.py.